# Database connection error

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jdbc, weblogic

I am getting the below error while making JDBC calls to the database. I am using -

- Microsoft SQL Server 2005
- Weblogic 10

> java.sql.SQLException:
>   [SQLState=null][ErrorCode=0]Unexpected
>   exception while enlisting XAConnection
>   java.sql.SQLException: Transaction
>   rolled back: Unknown reason
>                   at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.enlist(DataSource.java:1419)
>                   at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.refreshXAConnAndEnlist(DataSource.java:1331)
>                   at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:426)
>                   at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.connect(DataSource.java:383)
>                   at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:339)

Any thoughts as to why this is coming? Or any way i can debug it?

Comment: Perhaps stating the obvious, but it looks like a connection issue. Make sure URIs, port numbers, authentication etc etc is all good.

Comment: @Richard : Triple checked ... :( So trying to find a way as to how i can debug the issue.

Comment: Check this: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=735776&tstart=30 and also this: http://cn.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=731099&tstart=225 Maybe it helps...

Comment: WebLogic allows you to test the connection from the Administration Console. Are any exceptions reported when this test is conducted?

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds : Test connection works fine from the weblogic admin console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. There was a Infinite loop in my code which was causing the connection leak.

Answer (score 0):

Immediate thought:  check to see if you're using the right JDBC driver.  The "XA" part of your connection indicates that your call is attempting to join in a distributed transaction - that might not be supported with your version of weblogic/SQLServer 2005.

(Failing that, if you're writing your own database calls with the JDBC Driver, make sure you're not using an "XA" driver unless you want the distributed transaction features.)